# Missing argument 1 for ArticleController::update()

Tags: php, laravel

I want to edit and save some fields from my site, but this redirect me to an error.Can you tell me what's wrong with my view? Here is my view,route and controller, maybe you can have a look.This is not my code, but I'm trying to figure it out how to make it works.
`Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::update()`

**My view:**

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => '','url' => 'admin/article/update','id' => 'sky-form3']) !!}
```

**My route:**

```
Route::post('admin/article/update/{type?}/{id?}', 'ArticleController@update');
```

**Update function:**

```
public function update($type, $id)
    {
        if($type == "News")
        {
            $article = \App\News::find($id);
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject');
            $article->public = Request::input('public');
            $article->category_id = Request::input('category_id');
            $article->information = Request::input('information');
            $article->save();
        }

        if($type == "Opinion")
        {
            $article = \App\Opinion::find($id);
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject');
            $article->public = Request::input('public');
            $article->category_id = Request::input('category_id');
            $article->opinion = Request::input('opinion');
            $article->save();
        }

        if($type == "Event")
        {

            $article = \App\Event::find($id);
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject');
            $article->public = Request::input('public');
            $article->category_id = Request::input('category_id');
            $article->event_type_id = Request::input('event_type_id');
            $article->country = Request::input('country');
            $article->save();


        }

        if($type == "CareerSolution")
        {
            $article = \App\CareerSolution::find($id);
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject');
            $article->public = Request::input('public');
            $article->topic_category_id = Request::input('topic_category_id');
            $article->topic_subcategory_id = Request::input('topic_subcategory_id');
            $article->location = Request::input('location');
            $article->on_offer = Request::input('on_offer');
            $article->city = Request::input('city');
            $article->employment_type = Request::input('employment_type');
            $article->estimated_salary = Request::input('estimated_salary');
            $article->quantity = Request::input('quantity');
            $article->expires_at = Request::input('expires_at');
            $article->optional = Request::input('optional');
            $article->save();
        }

        if($article != ""){
            flash(trans($type.' has been Updated'), 'success');
        }else{
            flash(trans($type.' has not been updated'), 'warning');
        }

        return redirect(URL::previous());
    }
}
```

**My button**

`<a article_type="{{ $article['type'] }}" pop_up_id="{{ $article['type'] }}_{{ $article['id'] }}" role="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning modify">`

**Article.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articles';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'jobtitle', 'category_id','company','expired','formattedLocationFull','url','snippet','jobkey','approved','date','timestamp','modified_date','views','city','state','country','sponsored','indeedApply','jt','salary'
    ];

    // public function career_solution()
    // {
    //     return $this->hasMany('App\CareerSolution','topic_subcategory_id','id');
    // }
}
```

Comment: you should pass the `type` parameter too

Comment: how to add it in my url? Because `{{$article->type}}` doesn't work

Comment: if its post then why parameters?

Comment: I didn t make this code, I just want to know how to fix that, because I'm not doing great on php :)

Comment: how do you define your `update` method?

Comment: `public function update($type, $id)` like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your route like this

```
Route::post('admin/article/update/{type?}/id/{id?}', 'ArticleController@update')->name('update.article');
```

and you can simply use it as

`{{ route('update.article', ['type' => 'some_type', 'id' => 'some_id'] }}`

and then

```
    Form::open(array('route' => array('update.article', ['type' => 'some_type', 'id' => 'some_id']), 'method' => 'POST'))
    @csrf
```

Comment: Now it's working, but I m redirect to a 404 page. Maybe should I change this url from view? `{!! Form::open(['class' => '','url' => 'admin/article/event','id' => 'sky-form3']) !!}`

Comment: Use a named route and then pass the params to the named route. Updated the answer.

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:`. some help please :(

Comment: @AndreiNagy, check out now and make sure you've a csrf token in post request

Comment: First line is for route, third one is for my view, but second one where should be?

Comment: second one is an example showing how to use named routes in views. you can ignore it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196193/discussion-between-andrei-nagy-and-aditya-thakur).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your route in my opinion. `{type?}` is not defined, try to remove it from route and it should be fine.

```
Route::post('admin/article/update/{id?}', 'ArticleController@update');
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I've got same error : `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::update()`

Comment: what you get when you do  `dd($article);`? Because you try to find `$article` so you do not save it but update it. I'm curious if you find any article at all

Comment: try to put `$article->update();` instead of `$article->save();` and delete 
`if($article != ""){
            flash(trans($type.' has been Updated'), 'success');
        }else{
            flash(trans($type.' has not been updated'), 'warning');
        }` and check if problem still exists

Comment: same error...I updated my question with my button for edit, maybe can help

Comment: do you have Article model created? if yes, please paste as well

Comment: I updated my question.I have 3 types for articles: news/event and opinion. First, I want to make edit on event works.

Comment: and `dd($type)`? I think `$type` is not defined and that is the problem. You can add realtion to article HasMany type

Comment: `dd($type);` = `"Event"`

Comment: hmmm... I'm lost now ;). so you get $event and dd($id); you also get value?

Comment: `dd($id)` has value id of my event.

Comment: and did you try to adjust your form?
{!! Form::open(['class' => '','url' => 'admin/article/update', 'type' => 'Event', 'id' => 'sky-form3']) !!}

Comment: with this, after submit my edit page, i m redirected to a 404 page

Comment: and what error in says? so we are close, 'type' must be defined in form

Comment: It s not really an error, it s just error 404 for my page

Comment: and what is your URL, when you try to submit form?

Comment: `link.com/admin/article/update`. In my route I have `Route::post('admin/article/update/{type?}/{id?}', 'ArticleController@update');`. Maybe my link should be something like .... `link.com/admin/article/update/type/id` ? Im confused

Comment: it takes url from `{!! Form::open(['class' => '','url' => 'admin/article/update','id' => 'sky-form3']) !!}`

Comment: it will get when you submit form, but try to delete type {type?} and leave only {id?} in your route and also `$type` parameter from function leave just `public function update($id)` and see what happens. I'm also confused right now :/

Comment: yes, exactly, but in your route you pass also type, where it is missing in Form and I dont know how you define it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196195/discussion-between-andrei-nagy-and-kusy).

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a two optional parameters on your route, so you need to define them as an optional parameters in your `update` method

```
public function update($type = false, $id = false)
```

also you will need to make sure that you are passing them in your form open, it will be better to use route names with that

```
Form::open(array('route' => array('route.name', ['id' => $id, 'type' => $type])))
```

---

However, IMHO It will be better to avoid using multiple optional parameters on defining routes.

Comment: thank you for the answer, with this I've got undefined variable for id

Comment: you need to adjust the code and not using it as it , for example `['id' => 'your_id_value', 'type' => 'your_type_value']`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your route the function header should be: public function update($type=null, $id=null)

One point of improvement (does not solve your problem directly, but might help). Use models bindings! See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding